# Merge [tips] into [tips-and-tricks]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Can we merge [tips](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tips) into [tips-and-tricks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) (and maybe even synonymize)? They're identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nah, those tags both have to go. They're nothing but [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

I've called for Trogdor to have them removed.

Comment: Oh, maybe we can get them blocked as well.

Comment: If they come back...